# Number of ways of distributing 2 distinct balls in 2 distinct bins is 4, but why not 6?

Tags: combinatorics

No . ways of distributing 2 balls in 2 bins :

Balls $a,b$

Bins $1,2$

Taking ball configuration

$a$ $1 1 2 1 $

$b$ $1 2 1 2$
=4 correct

But taking bin configuration

$1$ $a b a,b    b,a$

$2$ $b a    a,b     b,a $
=6 !

What is wrong  in my understanding ?

Comment: No . ways of distributing 2 balls in 2 bins -:
Balls a,b
Bins 1,2
Taking ball configuration
a b 
1 1
1 2 
2 2
2 1
=4 correct 
But taking bin configuration
1      2 
a      b 
a,b
b,a
b      a
       a,b
       b,a
=6 !!! What is wrong  in my understanding ?

Answer (score 1):

Well. Suppose we have a red ball, denoted $R$, and a blue ball, denoted $B$. Assume we have two bins, Bin $1$ and Bin $2$.

Then we see that

**Case 1**. Bin $1$ has both $R$ and $B$; Bin $2$ has nothing.

**Case 2**. Bin $2$ has both $R$ and $B$; Bin $1$ has nothing.

**Case 3**. Bin $1$ has $R$; Bin $2$ has $B$.

**Case 4**. Bin $1$ has $B$; Bin $2$ has $R$.

There's no other case. So, $4$ cases in total.

**Additional**: This is also counting the number of functions mapping between two sets with $2$ elements, namely $2^2$.

Comment: CASE 4: A??? Do you mean R?

Comment: @YashJain Thanks.